# NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport();

Tags: android, apache, api, http, noclassdeffounderror

I am creating an Android application in Eclipse, and I keep getting

```
NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport();
```

I have looked through all the Stackoverflow answers on this issue before but I still cannot seem to fix it.

Here are the things that I've done:
* Downloaded `google-http-java-client-1.12.0-beta`
* Added the `libs` folder (with all the jars and properties files) to my project
* Added the files from the `dependencies` folder to the `libs` folder
* Right clicked on my project > properties > java build path > add jars > added all the .jar files from `libs`
* Clean and build project

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Importing libraries also matters order of import. Read "Article Extensions" in [my article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/) to know about import order of libraries.